# Create a nested grid with a self referencing table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have a table with following schema:

```
SELECT [ParkingCardId],
       [ParentParkingCardId],
       [CompanyId],
       [DateRequested],
       [StaffNo],
       [Name],
       [Section],
       [JobTitle],
       [Position],
       [Telephone],
       [Mobile],
       [Fax],
       [POBox],
       [Email],
       [Nationality],
       [Gender],
       [ShiftType],
       [Amount],
       [PassIssueDate],
       [PassExpiryDate]
FROM [DCAServices].[dbo].[ParkingCards];
```

The first two columns are key here: ParkingCardId is the PK and ParentParkingCardId, if not `NULL`, is pointing to another ParkingCardId in the same table and is, itself, a renew of a lost card case.

I want to display this information as hierarchical in Grid on MVC (Kendo) but my DAL is pure Entity Framework based and I have not used any Stored Procedures so far. I know it may not be easy to have a LINQ query to transform this data.

There is also a possibility that there may be generations of parents. A staff might be on his eights renewal. So the parent row on the grid may expand to show one child that may be a parent itself and so on.

I'm currently looking at search result that comes up against query like "Parent-Child relation in the same table"

Comment: should it be SQL query or C# code?

Comment: @Alexey It really depends on which one is achievable: If it cannot be an EF-LINQ c# code, then it has to be a view or an SP that I'll call from EF. So, preferably both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `SQL` will return hierarchical result with `Level` of current item

```
WITH cte as
(
  SELECT i.[ParkingCardId], i.[ParentParkingCardId], i.[CompanyId], i.[DateRequested], i.[StaffNo], i.[Name], i.[Section], i.[JobTitle], i.[Position], 
  i.[Telephone], i.[Mobile], i.[Fax], i.[POBox], i.[Email], i.[Nationality], i.[Gender], i.[ShiftType], i.[Amount], i.[PassIssueDate], i.[PassExpiryDate], 0 AS [Level]
  FROM [DCAServices].[dbo].[ParkingCards] i
  WHERE i.[ParentParkingCardId] is null

  UNION ALL

  SELECT i1.[ParkingCardId], i1.[ParentParkingCardId], i1.[CompanyId], i1.[DateRequested], i1.[StaffNo], i1.[Name], i1.[Section], i1.[JobTitle], i1.[Position], 
  i1.[Telephone], i1.[Mobile], i1.[Fax], i1.[POBox], i1.[Email], i1.[Nationality], i1.[Gender], i1.[ShiftType], i1.[Amount], i1.[PassIssueDate], i1.[PassExpiryDate], [Level] + 1
  FROM [DCAServices].[dbo].[ParkingCards] i1
  INNER JOIN cte
  ON cte.[ParkingCardId] = i1.[ParentParkingCardId]
 )
SELECT * From cte
ORDER BY [Level]
```

Check this link [Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

Comment: Is there a way to add an order by so that I can understand how a parking card progressed Level-wise?

Comment: @DoomerDGR8 if I got you correctly, check updated answer, `ORDER BY` is added there

Comment: That bit I tried but it just plain sorts of Levels. Now, I have my ParkingCard with Level 0. Then It was renewed a year later and we have level 1 and then I lost it and got a replacement at the level 3. I need this sorted together.

Comment: @DoomerDGR8 could be I didn't get you completely, but as I understood you need to change value for root level, you can change it here `0 AS [Level]`

Comment: your query is what I wanted. It is just formatting the information now. The data against which I'll be running this query has info regarding my parking card. I got it two years ago. First record created with parent id null and level 0. Then it got renewed a year later and a new row was inserted: parent id of level 0 and with level =1. Then I lost it and a replacement was issued: parent id that of level 1 and it's level = 2 and so on. I want to see these records/lineage together.

Comment: @DoomerDGR8 to be honest that's not clear for me, please provide example of data you have in DB, and result you are trying to get, and add it to initial post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166619/discussion-between-alexey-and-doomerdgr8).